# PHP imagejpeg() does not overwrite the image file instantly

Tags: php, imagejpeg

PHP imagejpeg() does not overwrite an existing image file immediately. It does work, but after an indefinite amount of time, sometimes an hour or many hours later. This weird behaviour started to happen after the server was changed and upgraded to PHP7 from PHP5.

The writing permission is properly given to the file saving destination folder. Also GD is enabled.

Following is the code snippet I'm using to save an image.

```
/* Get original image x y*/ 
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

/* calculate new image size with ratio */ 
$ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h); 
$h = ceil($height / $ratio); 
$x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2; 
$w = ceil($width / $ratio);

$path = 'profimg/'.$width.'_'.$filename;

$imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
                           0, 0,
                           $x, 0,
                           $width, $height,
                           $w, $h); 
imagejpeg($tmp, $path, 100); 
imagedestroy($image); 
imagedestroy($tmp);
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Could this be a browser cache problem? Try pressing <Ctrl-F5>.

Comment: Could it be a cached image you're seeing?

Comment: No, I tried cleaning cache on browser and Android studio for the mobile app. The issue is not in the previous server we used, the image is updated and loaded correctly there immediately. I made the php.ini files similar to the previous server, but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Turned out the DNS hosting platform is caching static content. Thanks a lot for your comments. I was struggling on the wrong end so far :)